# Eine Alternative zum Ausdruck «etwas auf die leichte Schulter nehmen»

Tags: phrase, idiom

> Er nimmt die Gefahr auf die leichte Schulter.

Kann man auch in diesem Zusammenhang den Ausdruck «etwas leicht nehmen» verwenden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eine Entsprechung, die auch für schriftliche Kommunikation taugt:

> unterschätzen

Dementsprechend:

> Er unterschätzt die Gefahr

Answer (score 2):

Kann man, ich würde aber «etwas leicht nehmen» eher im Kontext wie «das Leben leicht nehmen», «die Herausforderung leicht nehmen» oder ähnlichem verwenden. Bei der Gefahr würde ich eher zu «etwas (die Gefahr) zu leicht nehmen» oder «etwas (die Gefahr) nicht sehr ernst nehmen» tendieren.